# Find a decoupled explicit formula for a minimizer

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the energy

$F(u,v) = \int^1_0((\frac{1}{4}(u')^2+(v')^2 +\frac{1}{2}(u-v+1)^2)dx$

for $C^1$ functions u and v on the interval (0,1) that satisfy the boundary conditions u(0)=0,u(1)=2,v(0)=0,v(1)=4.

I have found the euler lagrange equations $u_0 -v_0 +1-.5u_0''=0$ and $-(u_0 -v_0 +1) - 2v_0''=0 $ but they require that I write $u_0,v_0$ as decoupled equations but im unsure how.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: If you multiply the first equation by $4$ and subtract the second equation from it, you should get an ODE for the function $w=u_0-v_0$.

Comment: Or notice that $(u-4v)'' = 0$ and solve for this given the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $(u-4v)'' = 0$, hence $u(t)-4v(t) = u(0)-4v(0)+ t(u'(0)-4v'(0))$.

$u(1)-4 v(1) = -14 = u'(0)-4v'(0)$, hence $u(t)-4v(t) =-14 t$.

Now use this to solve the ODE for $v$ (or $u$).

Since $2\ddot{v} = v-u-1$, we have $2\ddot{v} = v-u+1 = v-(4v-14 t)-1 = -3v +14 t -1$. So, solve $\ddot{v} = -\frac{3}{2}v+7t-\frac{1}{2}$.

I believe the solution is
$v(t) = \frac{1}{3}\cos( \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} t )-\frac{1}{3} \frac{\cos( \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} ) +1}{\sin( \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} )} \sin( \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} t )+\frac{14t-1}{3}$.

Comment: @copperhat when i attempt to solve the ode, what do i do with the second derivitive of v if im attempting to solve for u